# Which values of the viewBox are inherited in the cx, cy , and r of a circle

Tags: svg

I was just playing around with the below SVG:

```html
<svg width="100" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>
```

Now the width in the viewbox is 50 and the height is 50. proportionally to width in the viewbox is 2 units of the actual width I.E. `100/50 = 2` and the height is 4 units of the actual height I.E. `200/50 = 4`.

Now what i want to know is what is the actualy value of the 25's inside the `cx`, `cy` and `r` ?? is it `25*2 = 50` for all three ?? are any of the 3 not inheriting from the height of the viewbox ?? if not .. why not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now what i want to know is what is the actualy value of the 25's inside the cx, cy and r ?? is it 25*2 = 50 for all three ??

No. Your SVG isn't square like the viewBox. So the contents of the SVG are not simply scaled by 2x.

As you can see when you view the SVG. The circle is vertically centred in the 100x200 viewport.  With the default scaling rules (which can be changed with the  `preserveAspectRatio` attribute), the contents are being scaled up to the minimum of width and height.  In this case that's the width.  Then the circle gets vertically centred, because the hight is greater than the width..

The final result will be a circle that occupies the area from (0,50) to (100,150).

So you could say that the effective transformed values for `cx`,`cy`,`r` are `50`,`100`,`50`.

> are any of the 3 not inheriting from the height of the viewbox ?? if not .. why not ?

Nothing "inherits" from the viewBox.  The interaction of `viewBox`,`width` and `height` result in an [initial coordinate system](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InitialCoordinateSystem) transform.  That transform affects the scale and position of the objects in the SVG.

Comment: Thank i'll go through your answer a couple of more times for it to sink in ,but can you tell me where does r get its value form ? or rather what is the actual value of r ?

Comment: The actual value of `r` is 25, as per the file. But because of the scaling caused by the combination of width/height and viewBox, it is rendered at an effective radius of 50.

Comment: The 50x50 viewBox (and the SVG content area it corresponds to) gets scaled up so that it fits the SVG width of 100px.  But because your SVG ihas a height of 200px, the viewBox also gets translated down so that it is vertically centred. So there is a "space" of 50px above and below the circle. That's why I said that the effective transformed value of `cy` is 50+50=100.

Comment: so `cy` is 100 because the height value in the viewBox is 50 .. which is 1/4th of the actual height 200. so when u say cy = 25*4 .... am i right ??

Comment: No. Coords get doubled because viewBox.width (50) is half of SVG width (100).  So SVG contents get scaled by 2x. Scaled contents are now 100x100 (with cx,cy & r now 50). But the SVG viewport is 100x200. Because contents will get automatically vertically centred, that 100x100 will get moved down by 50 ((200-100)/2). So the cy will end up at an effective value of 100 (50+50).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best means to determine the values is to run getBBox() on the circle as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>ViewBox</title>
</head>

<body onload=showBB()>
<svg width="100" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
  <circle id=myCircle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>
<script>
function showBB()
{
  var bb=myCircle.getBBox()
  var bbx=bb.x
  var bby=bb.y
  var bbw=bb.width
  var bbh=bb.height
  var cx=bbx+5*bbw
  var cy=bby+5*bbh
  var r=.5*bbw
  console.log("r="+r+" cx="+cx+" cy="+cy)
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```